# Remove bloggers automatic 'add URL' feature to menu items

Tags: url, blogger

My Blogger template ([klarity](http://klarity-soratemplates.blogspot.com)) automatically adds my domain name infront of any link I want to add to my menu. For example: I want to create a link to my page 'about'. All I need to do is create a list item with a link pointing towards `/about.html`.

This is a problem when I want to link a menu item with an external domain. So if I want to create a link between the menu item 'shop' and www.myshop.com I cannot simply change the href of the link to www.myshop.com because blogger adds my domain name infront of it, making it look like: www.mydomain.com/www.myshop.com.

From what I understand Blogger does this through the following code: `data:post.url` or similar. I have looked for that kind of code and tried cutting it out but so far I have not managed to get rid of www.mydomain.com infront of every list item.

How can I remove www.mydomain.com from my menu items? This is the only solution I could think of, if there are any others please do suggest them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually figured out the problem, it was really easy:

Just change the link so that it looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.yourdomain.com">My domain</a>
```

Make sure you don't forget the http, otherwise you are going to get errors (thats's the mistake I made)